# What shader can I use to achieve a similar look to Alberto Mielgo's short film The Windscreen Wiper?

Tags: shaders

I am working on a short film and I am looking to achieve a similar look to Alberto Mielgo's short film The Windscreen Wiper (the character not the background). I love the flat colours look as well as the simplicity (not too many details on the face/ hair/ clothes. Are there any particular shaders I should be looking at? Any suggestions would be very welcome.[image]